# Extract data from different table with some condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Question: list down the status id needed for the report and query in the orders table

from order table needs this data

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('20210930', 'YYYYMMDD') 
AND ORDER_DATE < TO_DATE('20230328', 'YYYYMMDD')
AND ORDS_STKS_ID=75
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE DESC
```

from the status table need this data

```
select * from STATUS
where STAS_id=1
```

similarity

> 

ORDERS tbl=> ORDS_STAS_ID

> 

STATUS tbl=> STAS_id;

help me to display all data from status_id=1, 5, 71 from the STATUS table

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query  and add missing information

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a join, but it is unclear which column(s) are to be used for that.

```
select *
from orders o join status s on o.??? = s.???    --> this
where o.order_date >= date '2021-09-30' 
  and o.order_date <  date '2023-03-28'
  and o.ords_stks_id = 75
  and s.stas_enable_approve = 1
order by o.order_date desc;
```

I marked the 2nd line; you should fix `???`s and put appropriate columns names in there.

Maybe, just *maybe* it is

```
on o.ords_stas_id = s.stas_enable_approve
```

Comment: not working.. help me to sole

Comment: I can't, not unless you edit the question and follow suggestions posted in comments.